# Portainer - Force Docker image repull even if no Git change

Tags: portainer

I created a stack based on a docker-compose file with polling mechanism enabled. The thing is the docker-compose definition hosted on the Git repository almost never changes but the Docker image is updated quite oftenly.

I have the feeling as the docker-compose hasn't been modified the docker image isn't repulled.

I tried to enable "Re-pull image" option in Portainer but same issue.

This is how the service are defined in the docker-compose file:

```
services:
  my-awesome-service:
    image: ghcr.io/mycompany/awesome-software:latest
```

Note: In Portainer, if I click on the button "pull and redeploy", it works.